# Spring security - Disable logout redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security with REST, and I'm using the URL (`/logout`) as an endpoint for my logout method. But after calling this method, it redirect me to (`/login?logout`), I know this is the spring `logOutSuccessUrl`. And I want to get rid of the redirection. This is my code:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
         .and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
         .and().httpBasic().disable().logout()
         .disable()
       //  .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))
          .csrf().disable();

}
```

I tried to use `HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler` but it didn't work, and even setting `logoutSuccessUrl()` doesn't change anything.

Do you know how can I disable this redirection?

Comment: This article details how to disable the logout redirect: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-disable-logout-redirects

Answer (score 49):

Following code works for me (notice that it doesn't have `logout().disable()`)

```
http.logout().permitAll();
http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler((new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK)));
```

Comment: Try setting logging level of spring security to debug, it might give you a hint. If using spring boot, you can add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` to application.properties

Comment: @uncallable Did you get it to work? I am having the similar issue. Tried all solutions, nothing works.

Comment: I'm using spring-security 4.2.0.RELEASE with XML config and it works.

Comment: We don't need to pass OK explicitly it is the default value.

Answer (score 27):

So since there is no accepted answer yet, i post my solution, which worked for me:

```
.logout()
.logoutUrl("/api/user/logout")
.permitAll()
.logoutSuccessHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> {
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
})
.and()
```

Just return a clean HTTP_OK (200) after successful logout - spring won't redirect you in this case

Comment: Dude, you made my day. Many thanks, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Foo those who use XML config, here is the equivalent snippet for the one given by [Tahir Akhtar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18027/tahir-akhtar).

**Within `<http>` element, configure the `<logout>` element as follows:**

```
<logout
    logout-url          = "/some/path/for/logout"
    invalidate-session  = "true"
    delete-cookies      = "JSESSIONID"
    success-handler-ref = "httpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler"
/>
```

**And define `httpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler` bean as follows:**

```
<bean
    id      = "httpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler"
    class   = "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this method:

```
.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("enter address here where you want to go after logout")
```

Comment: OP wants to get rid of the redirect as the /logout is being called from a REST client (probably AJAX requests from a browser)

Comment: The question was to disable the redirect, not to change it to a different url.

Comment: This may not have solved the OP problem but it solved mine.  This was making it go in a loop, along with the 'access="permitAll"'.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this

http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/thisistomisleadlogoutfilter"));

This effectively redirects /thisistomisleadlogoutfilter to login?logout. As such you should be able to use /logout instead

Answer (score 1):

for logoutSuccessXXX() action, do not forget to add permitAll() since the cookie is cleared after the logout() method is called. So my sample solution is:

```
http
   ......
   .and()
       .logout()
           .logoutUrl("/logout")
           .logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutSuccess")
           **.permitAll()**
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, none of the answers above worked for me for different reasons (Using Spring Boot 2.6.6 + Thymeleaf).

Simplest solution that worked for me was implementing a `POST` form with a valid CSRF token in it. And rest of the default login/logout implementation provided by spring security just works out of the box.

So my web security config uses bare-bone defaults provided by spring-boot:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .fullyAuthenticated()
        .and().formLogin();
    }
```

and my template looks like (using BS5 dropdowns):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li>
        <form action="/logout" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit">Sign out</button>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Please DON'T** sacrifice the security (unless you have a valid reason for it) by disabling the CSRF token validation `http.csrf().disable()` just to be able to make `GET /logout` work without redirects, as recommended as *solution* by many neglectful articles around the web.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
@PostMapping(value = "/oauth/revoke")
public void revokeToken(Authentication authentication) {
    ofNullable(authentication).ifPresent(auth -> {
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.getAccessToken((OAuth2Authentication) auth);

        ofNullable(accessToken).ifPresent(oAuth2AccessToken -> {
            ofNullable(oAuth2AccessToken.getRefreshToken()).ifPresent(tokenStore::removeRefreshToken);
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
        });
    });
}
```

[From this gist](https://gist.github.com/saniaky/c86fbcead2a8dae76e1f0fef6c1b7f67)

Which worked perfectly.  I recommend doing this over the logout() override primarily because it (well, it works, but other than that) preserves the oauth2 basic flow (/oauth/revoke) instead of using /logout or similar.

Hope that helps!