# spring security /logout not working cross origin requests

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

My AngularJS application has a login and logout button. 
The login button works fine and also all other requests that are send to my backend.

The problem occurs when I try to logout.

I am getting following error.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/logout. The request was` `redirected to 'http://localhost:8081/login?logout', which is disallowed for` `cross-origin requests that require preflight.`

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('emifEkolFinderApp').controller('logoutController', ['$scope', 'CONFIGURATION', 'AccessToken', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, CONFIGURATION, AccessToken, $http, $location) {
    $scope.logout = function () {
        var userUrl = 'http://' + CONFIGURATION.OAUTH_SERVER_IP_AND_PORT + '/logout';
        var data = AccessToken.set().access_token;
        $http.post(userUrl,JSON.stringify("{}")).then(function (successCallback) {
            AccessToken.destroy();
            console.log("Revokin'");
            $location.path("/");
        }, function (errorCallback) {
            console.log(errorCallback);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Spring security config:

```
@Configuration
public class ServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}

}
```

my CORS filter:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, HEAD");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization,  cache-control, content-type, Origin, key");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "*");
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

I am really touching in the dark here. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is this related with the redirect after logout, try turn off this redirect by implementing a LogoutSuccessHandler, like the question:
[Spring security - Disable logout redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354405/spring-security-disable-logout-redirect)

`http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler((new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler (HttpStatus.OK)));`

Answer (score 0):

Well Spring Security default behavior for logout is that, after successful logout, it redirects the request to the `default logout succes url` that is by default `/login?logout`.

This is a redirect action and while using rest calls redirect are not allowed. Hence your logout code breaks. You need to add a custom logout handler that does not redirect you to another path.

And how to do that.Create a custom Logout handler and send response from there something like

```
http.formLogin().and().logout().addLogoutHandler(new LogoutHandler() {
            @Override
            public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            }
        });
```