# Spring Security: Still can't disable redirect with logoutSuccessHandler

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, spring-security, http-redirect

I am using Spring Security with Oauth2 to secure RESTful API. My `WebSecurityConfig` class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(
                    SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ristore/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        http.logout().permitAll();
        http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler((new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK)));
    }

    @Override  
    @Bean  
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {  
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();  
    }

    @Bean
    public RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler mySuccessHandler(){
        return new RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler myFailureHandler(){
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 

            DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://ldap.mdanderson.edu:389/dc=mdanderson,dc=edu");
            contextSource.setUserDn("cn=ris_flow,ou=service accounts,ou=institution,ou=service accounts,dc=mdanderson,dc=edu");
            contextSource.setPassword("!BMpl@tform2O15");
            contextSource.setReferral("follow"); 
            contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
            LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer = auth.ldapAuthentication();
            ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer
                .userDnPatterns("cn={0},ou=institution,ou=people")
                .userSearchBase("")
                .contextSource(contextSource); 
        }
    }
}
```

In order to disable redirect for logout, I added the `logoutSuceessHandler`.

At the front end, I wrote the following function to handle logout event with AngularJS:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
        $http.post(SERVER + '/logout', {}).success(function() {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
            $location.path("/");
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log("Logout failed")
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        });
    };
```

However, I still got the following error at logout:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/logout. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost:8080/login?logout', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

I tried every solution in the following similar posts and nothing seems to stop the redirect. [spring security /logout not working cross origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460045/spring-security-logout-not-working-cross-origin-requests) and [Spring security - Disable logout redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354405/spring-security-disable-logout-redirect).

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

After I turned on debug mode in logging spring security, here is the output for logout request. Why is it trying match /logout request to /oauth/token?

[image]

Comment: @dur Spring Security 4.0.3

Comment: @dur just like google or yahoo, you have login and you have logout. If it is run on a shared computer, the person might want to logout before the next person log in the same site.

Comment: @dur so instead of making a call to the server, you are suggesting that I do logout entirely on client side? Just clear the cookie and token, etc?

Comment: @dur just like you said, there is really no need to involve the server when logging out, as long as the token is cleared from client, it should be ok. I think I will not make any http request for logout.